# PHP class COM not found

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use **COM** object in my script  on xampp server and getting error

> fatal error class COM not found

Can anyone help?

**Code:**

```
//create an ADO connection and open the database
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
$conn->open("PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\WebData\Northwind.mdb");
```

Comment: Have you tried installing it/seeing if it's installed correctly?

Comment: i have added [COM_DOT_NET]
     extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
in php.ini but still getting the same error..

Comment: Have you referred to DanFromGermany's answer? or looked at the installation guide?

Comment: yes.. i have downloaded dll file but could not figure out the problem

Comment: Is that a "yes" to both questions?

Comment: yeah..plx help me out

Comment: If it's still not recognising it's installed, it's not installed - Have you restarted Apache?

Comment: i have restarted xampp

Answer (score 2):

> As of PHP 5.3.15 / 5.4.5, this extension requires php_com_dotnet.dll
>   to be enabled inside of php.ini in order to use these functions.
>   Previous versions of PHP enabled these extensions by default.
>
> You are responsible for installing support for the various COM objects
>   that you intend to use (such as MS Word); we don't and can't bundle
>   all of those with PHP.

From http://php.net/manual/en/com.installation.php

> From PHP 5.4.5, COM and DOTNET is no longer built into the php
>   core.you have to add COM support in php.ini:
>
> [COM_DOT_NET] extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
>
> Otherwise you will see this in your error log: Fatal error:  Class
>   \'COM\' not found
>
> The extension is included with php 5.4.5 for Windows.

From http://php.net/manual/en/com.installation.php#109552

Comment: added these lines and downloaded php_com_dotnet.dll but still getting the same error .. can u plx tell where to add these lines in php.ini ? in [php] section ???

Comment: Have you restarted Apache?

Comment: * Have you restarted PHP + added the lines to the correct php.ini? (debug with `phpinfo();`)

Comment: i have restarted xampp server

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 5.3.15 / 5.4.5, this extension requires php_com_dotnet.dll to be enabled inside of php.ini in order to use these functions. Previous versions of PHP enabled these extensions by default.

You are responsible for installing support for the various COM objects that you intend to use (such as MS Word); we don't and can't bundle all of those with PHP.

If u have instaled please first check if extension loaded in expression.

**Example:**

```
<?php
if (!extension_loaded('gd')) {
    if (!dl('gd.so')) {
        exit;
    }
}

// update 

if (!extension_loaded('com')) {
    echo "COM no exists";
}
```

Comment: This code is Example to show u how to check if extension is loaded.

Comment: the result is com no exists.. i have installed php_com_dotnet.dll as well as added [com_dot_net] extension= php_com_dotnet.dll                  what should i do             can u plx tell where to add these two loines in php.ini ??